# Should I use selenium, appium or selendroid?

Tags: android, selenium, appium, selendroid

Beginner programmer here- I want to convert a small program I made into an app- the original program uses selenium to load a website, ask for a username+ password, and auto logs you in and clicks a bunch of boxes and dropdowns, then exits.

I want to turn this all into an android app- I have a couple questions:

1. do I have to rewrite all my code in android studio
2. can I still use selenium or do I have to set up appium/ selendroid and if so, which one?

basically, the app should open up a UI screen, and ask for a username and password. From there it will open up a browser and click a bunch of stuff and that is it.

lots of love!

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving some important high level observations

**App Type Cases**

1. If your AUT is an android/ios native app then yes you have to use Appium or native frameworks like Espresso,XCUTest etc

2.If your AUT is a webapp with just a different user-agent like mobile,tablet etc then same tests can be used with little modification e.g.

2.1 You can use mobile emulation with Selenium - Chrome browser with mobile dimension

2.2 You can also use Appium with Emulator or real device - Chrome browser in Mobile device.

3. If your AUT is a hybrid app i.e. partly native and partly chrome session then 
   you have to use Appium

**If Existing Tests Cases already present**

1. If your browser application tests are already written in Selenium then you can use a tools which supports selenium methods like Appium for writing your android or ios app tests, this will help you in knowing scenarios to cover.
2. If your app is webapp then existing test cases will work with little modifications
3. If your app is hybrid then few existing cases will work which are under webview.

**If Existing Tests Cases are not present**

You are free to choose language of your choice as per knowledge and tool which best suites to your application.

Original Question - I want to turn this all into an android app- I have a couple questions:

do I have to rewrite all my code in android studio

> > Yes if native app, Partially yes if hybrid and No if webapp

can I still use selenium or do I have to set up appium/ selendroid and if so, which one?

> > for webapp you can use selenium but for hybrid or native app Appium is must. Read documentation and see which is easy for you to pick up.

**Note -** Selendroid is deprecated because it was used with very old Android version device e.g.  Android IceCream 4.2 or below version or API level < 17